# Ampscript Not Working on Send SMS Journey Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, lookup, sms

I'm trying to create a journey to send a SMS with some personalization strings.

The Journey is sending the SMS but all the ampscript variables come in empty,

I'm using the following code:

```
%%[ 
SET @CEL = MOBILE_NUMBER 
SET @DE = 'Jornada_Indicado_Vaga - 2019-02-07T094203121'
SET @FIELD = 'IndicadoParaVaga__c:Celular_SMS__c'
SET @NomeVaga = LookUp(@DE , 'IndicadoParaVaga__c:Vaga__r:Name' , @FIELD  ,@CEL) 
SET @LinkVaga = LookUp(@DE , 'IndicadoParaVaga__c:LinkVagaSite__c' , @FIELD ,@CEL) 
]%% 
Ola! Somos da Connekt e voce foi indicado para a vaga %%=v(@NomeVaga)=%% , mais detalhes no link %%=v(@LinkVaga)=%%
```

I tested the code in a Cloud Page, just changing the MOBILE_NUMBER to a static number and it worked normally.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found out there was a name with the ' º ' character, just did a replace and it worked fine